# Rails - Using .uniq on an array inside a multidimensional array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a multidimensional array like so

```
 b = [["1", ["val1", "val2", "val2", "val3", "val3"]], ["2", ["val1", "val1", "val2", "val2", "val3"]]
```

The second value in the array is another array. I'm trying to get these values inside the array that is in place of the second value to be unique (kinda hard to explain).

I looked at the documentation and the closest I could get was `b.uniq { |s| s.second }`. This just checks the second value has no duplicates with other second values. So in this case if the array in the second was the same as another array in the second value it would remove the duplicate.

I cant get it to remove the duplicates inside the arrays that are in the array value. **Here is what I want it to endup like**

```
[["1", ["val1", "val2", "val3"]], ["2", ["val1", "val2", "val3"]]
```

Comment: Sorry I though it would be a little confusing. I have edited my question.

Comment: You don't have a multidimensional array, there's no such thing in Ruby. You have an array of arrays. There is a difference.

Comment: @muistooshort Thanks! I feel silly now. I guess most knew what I mean't

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the solution :

```
arr = arr.map{|x| [x[0],x[1].uniq]}
```

Comment: I prefer `arr.map {|a, b| [ a, b.uniq ] }`, but my personal preference aside this solution is perfect.

Comment: @Jordan is there any real advantage such as speed over your way compared to this answer? Or is it just a different way of reading/ writing it

Comment: There's no performance difference. I just find it more readable.

Answer (score 0):

This will filter your original array in the way you want:

```
b.each {|ar| ar.second.uniq!}
```

Comment: I interpreted "Here is what I want it to endup like" as "b should endup like this", which would mean "I want to mutate b". I don't understand what you mean with having `b` on a second line though.

Answer (score 0):

This code should do the trick.

```
b = [["1", ["val1", "val2", "val2", "val3", "val3"]], ["2", ["val1", "val1", "val2", "val2", "val3"]]]
i = 0
while i < b[1].length
    b[i][1] = b[i][1].uniq
    i += 1
end
p b
```

This will return `[["1", ["val1", "val2", "val3"]], ["2", ["val1", "val2", "val3"]]]`.